# Showing thislinear operator on an inner product space is its own transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $H$ be the inner product space of continuous real valued functions defined on $[0,1]$ where
$(\alpha\mid\beta)=\int_{0}^{1} \alpha(u)\beta(u)du$

Put $K(s,t)=\min\{s,t\}-st$.  Define $T∈L(V,V)$ by

$\int_{0}^{1} K(s,t) \alpha(t) dt$

How do I show that $T^t=T$?  I need to show that $(T(\alpha)\mid\beta)=(\alpha\mid T(\beta))$ for all $(\alpha,\beta)∈H^2$, correct?

Comment: Yes.  It ends up just being a change in order of integration.  Just apply the definitions.

Comment: Any suggestions with how to start showing that?

Comment: Write down what (T(α)∣β) means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to show that $(T(\alpha)\mid\beta)=(\alpha\mid T(\beta))$ for all $(\alpha,\beta)∈H^2$, correct?

Yes. To see this, write \begin{align}
(T(\alpha)\mid\beta)&=\int_0^1T(\alpha)(s)\beta(s)\mathrm ds\\
&=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \alpha(t)\min\{s,t\}\mathrm dt\right)\beta(s)\mathrm ds\\
&=\iint_{[0,1]^2} \alpha(t)\beta(s)\min\{s,t\}\mathrm dt\mathrm ds.
\end{align}
Then change the order of integration.

Note that it would work more generally if $K(s,t)=K(t,s)$ for each $s$ and $t$.